# Place button in the bottom of maps activity

Tags: android, android-activity, maps

I have a button in the upper left corner, i need another button and i want it to be where is the "google" logo, in the lower left corner.
This is what the activity looks like.
[image]

And this is the code, i want buttonChatGlobal to be in the lower left corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAcercar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Acercar/Alejar"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonChatGlobal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="ChatGlobal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />




</fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just replace this code below with your button you want**

```
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChatGlobal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#359c5e"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="ChatGlobal"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your Views inside a `ViewGroup` to align them you can use `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or other `ViewGroup` here I'm using `FrameLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" >
<fragment
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAcercar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#359c5e"
    android:gravity="top|start" // top left
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="Acercar/Alejar"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonChatGlobal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#359c5e"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start" // bottom left
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="ChatGlobal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</FrameLayout>
```